# error message when building using the atom text-editor

Tags: atom-editor

I'm a newbie and I am trying to run my first "Hello World!" program using atom editor.  I have installed the build package but when I tried to build I get an error message saying 'no eligible build target.  No configuration to build this project exists.' I am using ruby. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an old question, however I faced the same issue, hence would like call out on the solution I followed:-

When using "atom-build" package in Atom Editor, whenever you upgrade the package, you may have encountered this issue.
To fix this issue in your environment, what you need to do is:-

Atom Editor Menu:-
File -> "Add Project Folder"
Select your existing JS Project.

Once done, you should be able to use the "atom-build" package again, by invoking the build commands.

Refer:-
https://github.com/noseglid/atom-build/issues/230